# Google Play Store won't download apps after reinstalling

Tags: google-play-store, rooting

I had mistakenly uninstalled the stock Play Store on my rooted Lava Iris X1 Mini running Android 4.4. I reinstalled it as a system app after downloading the apk from an external site. Now, I cannot download any apps from the store, because as soon as the download starts, play store crashes. It doesn't even work when it's installed as a user app. Clearing data and cache of Google Play Services also doesn't fix the problem. Any way to prevent this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading the play store from [GApps](http://opengapps.org/). You will probably want the pico version... You then have to flash it with a custom recovery (e.g. [TWRP](https://twrp.me/)).

Good Luck ;)